# Call Container running on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Linux EC2 with docker running inside of it.
Docker is running 3 services. 2 are workers and one is an API.

I want to be able to call that API from outside the system but I am getting "This site can't be reached".
The service is running and the call is a simple `ping` which works locally through VS so I don't believe that is the issue.

My security group has all traffic allowed with `0.0.0.0/0`.

I have attempted the following urls but no luck:

- `http://ec2-{public-ip}.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ping`
- `http://{public-ip}/ping`
- `http://{public-ip}/172.17.0.2/ping  (containers IP address)`

Comment: Your container is listening on port 80? Also if you `curl localhost` from the instance, does it work?

Comment: No it is 'Connection refused' but I have EXPOSE 80 in the docker file so assumed that would do it

Comment: `EXPOSE` by itself does not expose anything. When you run your container you have to explicitly allow it using `-p 80:80` option.

Comment: Ah yes that worked. Thanks @Marcin

Comment: Perfect. Go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

[EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) does not actually "exposes" a port:

> The EXPOSE instruction **does not actually publish the port**. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, **use the -p flag on docker** run to publish and map one or more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports.

Thus, to expose port 80 from your container to the instance you have to use `-p 80:80` option.